# How to return multipart/form-data in response from WCF service?

Tags: wcf

In my WCF service I need to return MIME Multipart data (a text file) back to client in the response. Althoug the response returned to the client, I don't see the data being returned. As a matter of fact, I don't see anything I setup on the server side being returned to the client. Could someone shed some light on this? Here is what I have in my code for building and returning response:

```
        MultipartFormDataContent formData = new MultipartFormDataContent("myboundary");
        HttpResponseMessage responseMsg = new HttpResponseMessage();
        try
        {
            using (Stream fs = File.OpenRead("C;\\mydata.txt"))
            {
                formData.Add(new StreamContent(fs), "Payload", "mydata.txt"); 
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ServiceUtil.LogMessage(ex.Message);
        }
        responseMsg.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
        responseMsg.Content = formData;

        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentLength = 2048;
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers["Accept"] = "multipart/form-data";
    }
```

Comment: Check your file path with the semicolon. Are you throwing an exception trying to open "C;\\mydata.txt"?

Comment: Are you mixing WCF with ASP.NET Web API? WCF doesn't understand the `HttpResponseMessage` class (and others from System.Net.Http), unless you have a custom formatter which understands it.

Comment: The semicolon is just a typo when I tried to simplify the file path in my post. Sorry about it.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to use some Web API functionality in my WCF service so that I can serve HTTP MIME Multipart requests. I have successfully gotten the request received (it also contains multipart/form data) and processed. But I am having trouble return the multipart data back in response.

Comment: carlos: lf I can't use any of the System.Net.Http stuff, is there a way that I can return multipart data back in a response to client from my WCF service? I think the old WCF REST Starter kit used to support it. Is that still an option? I just need to have something to get this working.